# How to persist permissions with security scope bookmarks in a OS X sandboxed app

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, appstore-sandbox

I am trying to persist read/write permissions to Applications folder through security-scoped bookmarks but unsuccessfully.

I use grandAccess() to open a panel and select the Applications folder and gain permissions. At the same time, the panel's URL is stored as a security-scoped bookmark in UserDefaults. Then I can delete apps in the Applications folder with FileManager.

When I relaunch my app, I resolve the stored bookmark for Applications folder path and while the startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() returns TRUE for this URL, If I try to delete the application I then get a permission error.

Any idea why this happens???

My code is below:

```
// Move to Trash

        let startAccess = SecurityScopeManager.shared.startAccess()
        guard startAccess == true else {
            log.warning("Starting file access failed")
        }

        do {
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: application.path)
            try FileManager.default.trashItem(at: url, resultingItemURL: nil)
        } catch let error {
            log.error(error)
        }
```

// End

```
class SecurityScopeManager: NSObject {

static let shared       = SecurityScopeManager()
private let defaultsKey = DefaultsKeys.securityScopeBookmark.rawValue

private var url: URL?

func grandAccess() -> Bool {

    guard resolveBookmarkData() == false else {
        return true
    }

    let success = runPanel()

    return success
}

private override init() {
    super.init()
}

/// In the panel, I select the Applications folder and press the Open button
private func runPanel() -> Bool {

    let applicationsFolderPath  = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationDirectory, in: .localDomainMask).first!
    let panel                   = NSOpenPanel()
    panel.canChooseDirectories  = true
    panel.canChooseFiles        = false
    panel.directoryURL          = FileManager.default.urls(for: .userDirectory, in: .localDomainMask).first!

    if panel.runModal() == NSModalResponseOK {

        guard let url = panel.url, url == applicationsFolderPath else {
            return false
        }

        return storeBookmarkData(url: url)

    } else {

        return false

    }
}

/// Save bookmark data to UserDefaults. Returns true if success
private func storeBookmarkData(url: URL) -> Bool {

    do {

        let data = try url.bookmarkData(options: .withSecurityScope, includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, relativeTo: nil)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: defaultsKey)
        return true

    } catch {

        log.error(error.localizedDescription)
        return false
    }
}

/// Load bookmark data from UserDefaults
private func resolveBookmarkData() -> Bool {

    guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: defaultsKey) else {
        return false
    }

    do {

        var isStale = Bool()
        url         = try URL(resolvingBookmarkData: data, options: .withSecurityScope, relativeTo: nil, bookmarkDataIsStale: &isStale)

        if isStale { // If cannot update bookmark delete previous bookmark data
            UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: defaultsKey)
        }

        return true

    } catch {

        log.error(error)
        return false

    }
}

func startAccess() -> Bool {

    _ = resolveBookmarkData()

    guard url != nil else {
        _ = grandAccess()
        return false
    }

    let result = url?.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() ?? false
    return result

}

func stopAccess() {
    url?.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
}
```

}

**UPDATE 1**

What I discovered is that if I select in the panel the exact application that I want to delete (and not the Application directory )and save the bookmark of its path then it works.

The problem occurs when I select the Application folder in the panel. Then I don't have permission to delete an app under that directory after the relaunch of my app and the resolve of the stored bookmark.

**UPDATE 2**

I made a trial to delete a file under Desktop folder with security scoped bookmark and it worked. The issue comes with a bookmark for Applications folder.

Comment: Would it make sense to use CoreData for persistence and set while using the app. When the app is relaunched read from core data

Comment: @user1046037the problem is not where to persist the data but why when I successfully resolve the stored data the permissions don't work...

Comment: @memis I am trying to use your code as base, but to load additional resources for a Web View (unsuccessfully for the moment...) and I think your problem was that when your first attempt to start access and the bookmark isn't in Defaults `resolveBookmarkData()`, the bookmark URL is `nil`, so it try to `grandAccess()` and run the panel to select a folder, and end by saving the bookmark. You started with `startAccess()` but the first time if the bookmark doesn't exists, the method `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` is never called.